# Find the Fisher information matrix for the MLE of a Multinomial

Tags: multinomial-distribution

Please help me how to find the Fisher information matrix for the MLE of a Multinomial ...
It is said that considering $n$ and $p$ constraints in multinomial distribution.
In other words, when $p$ has $k$-dimension, real parameter number is $k-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fisher information function is the variance of the score function, so you start by finding the latter.  If you have an observed data vector $\mathbf{X} \sim \text{Mu}(\mathbf{p})$ using the probability vector $\mathbf{p} =(p_1,...,p_k)$ then you get the log-likelihood function:

$$\ell_\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{p}) = \text{const} + \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \log(p_i),$$

which gives you the score function:

$$s_\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{p}) \equiv \nabla \ell_\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{p}) = \bigg( \frac{x_1}{p_1},...,\frac{x_k}{p_k} \bigg) = \text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \mathbf{x}.$$

Consequently, the Fisher information matrix is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{p})
\equiv \mathbb{V}(s_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{p})) 
&= \mathbb{V}(\text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \mathbf{X}) \\[12pt]
&= \text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \mathbb{V}(\mathbf{X}) \text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \\[12pt]
&= n \text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) [\text{diag}(\mathbf{p}) - \mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}^\text{T}] \text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \\[12pt]
&= n [\text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) - (\text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \mathbf{p}) (\text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) \mathbf{p})^\text{T}] \\[12pt]
&= n [\text{diag}(1/\mathbf{p}) - \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^\text{T}] \\[12pt]
&= n \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1-p_1}{p_1} & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
-1 & \frac{1-p_2}{p_2} & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & \frac{1-p_3}{p_3} & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & \frac{1-p_k}{p_k} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}$$

The above treatment is for the full parameter vector with $k$ elements, but you can reduce this to the corresponding parameter vector with $k-1$ elements by taking $p_k = 1-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i$.  In the latter case you would rewrite the score function using this equivalence and then you would get a $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ invertible variance matrix.  I will leave this as a useful exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you! very helpful!

Comment: @Ben. Hi, I directly compute the co-variance matrix $\Sigma$ of the estimator $\mathbf{p}$ and get the result in [Thm 14.6](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/wasserman-multinomial.pdf). I believe the Fisher information matrix you gave is correct. However, I find $\mathcal{L}$ does not equal to the inverse matrix of $\Sigma$. Do you know why?

Comment: @ Ben: can this matrix be used to derive the formulas for the variance of each "p_ij"?

Comment: I cannot comment on Ben's answer so I have to put my response here. Actually, I have the name Ben too, so please call me Ben2 in this post. s(p) is not correct. Note that p1 + ... + pk = 1. From another perspective, pk is a function of others. So when you take derivative to p1, the result is not x1/p1. The evidence that the final matrix is wrong is from Mingzhou Liu's comment above. The final Fisher information matrix should be a (k-1)-by-(k-1) matrix. And then the covariance matrix can be got by taking inverse. Meanwhile, the covariance between pk and others can be viewed as the covariance be

Comment: @Ben -- Please note that the matrix should be of order $k - 1$.  Your info matrix couldn't give the correct asymptotic variance of MLE (it is not invertible).

Comment: It is not invertible because here I am using the parameter vector $\mathbf{p} = (p_1,...,p_k)$ of order $k$.  If you want to use the reduced parameter vector then you would make appropriate changes to the last element.

Comment: This is a classical example, most references I am aware of presented $I(p)$ as an order $k - 1$ invertible matrix. Besides, OP does mention that *real parameter number is $k - 1$*, so I think a standard answer should be of order $k - 1$.

Comment: Fair enough --- I have added a final paragraph to note the general method by which you would do this, but in this case I think I will leave that as an exercise for OP.